# msdeploy Password unknown characters

Tags: powershell, command-line, jenkins, msdeploy

I am trying to setup a Jenkins job for MsDeploy V3 to sync the source and target, but my EC2 machine has weird characters as its password. Here is my command for the Job:

```
MyApp-Test.deploy /Y /M:My-Connection-String.amazonaws.com /U:Administrator /P:rw)(&wq=WQe
```

Does anyone know the escape character for these:

&  (   )  =  %  ^

Comment: did you get this to work?

Comment: If it's calling a deploy.cmd file generated by msbuild under the covers, I think you need to escape the & with a triple escape of ^^^.

Answer (score 0):

Try quoting the complete **/P** flag

```
MyApp-Test.deploy /Y /M:My-Connection-String.amazonaws.com /U:Administrator \"/P:rw)(&wq=WQe\"
```

Answer (score 0):

Try triple double quotes, it works fine for me with msdeploy in powershell.

```
"""rw)(&wq=WQe""""
```

Answer (score -3):

You don't need to escape the characters. Just single-quote the entire password:

```
MyApp-Test.deploy /Y /M:My-Connection-String.amazonaws.com /U:Administrator /P:'rw)(&wq=WQe'
```

Comment: This did not work for me.
It prints msdeploy.exe, with the first half of the password, then it prints, _second half of password_ is not recognized as an internal or external command